# Regex for matching numeric with format 99.99

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

So far I have: `/\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}/` . But I don't want to include any other character other than numbers (don't want a0.12). This is for an input field with maxlength set to 5. Basically the input field should only allow numeric with format "99.99". Any thoughts?

Comment: `/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/`

Comment: Beat me to it! But, yep, looks fine

Comment: This is enough `\d{2}.\d{2}`

Comment: No negative numbers, then?

Comment: Try this `/^(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,2})$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,2})$/
```

- matches `9`, `99`, `9.99`, `99.9` and
- doesn't matches `9.`, `99.`.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using this one. It matches your requirement.

```
/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> /\d{2,2}.\d{2,2}/

The expression {2,2} will help you to limit the minimum and maximum length of a pattern to two. I think {2} should also work.